# Check heroku app's stack in buildpack

Tags: heroku, buildpack

How can I get heroku stack of the app for which buildpack is being executed.
I would like to invalidate the caches, if the stack has been changed since last build.
Example usecase: Apps migrating to the Celadon Cedar-14 Stack.

Answer (score 0):

That's an old question but here is the answer. Just run the following command from your app folder with heroku toolbet installed.

```
$ heroku stack --app your-heroku-app-name
```

Here is the documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack